# /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am using capistrano for deployment of rails application. But while i am deploying my rails code into server i am getting following error.

```
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing on host 00.00.00.00: bundle exit status: 126
bundle stdout: /home/rod/.rvm/scripts/set: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/home/rod/.rvm/scripts/set: line 19: /usr/local/bin/bundle: Success
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Where have you installed ruby?

Comment: I am using rvm. My ruby path is ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby

Comment: seems like you should install bundler. run `gem install bundler` and then try again.

Comment: I already install bundler

Comment: Make sure you have `capistrano-rvm` gem in the Gemfile. It is looking in `/usr/bin/ruby` currently (which is default capistrano behavior) but this is not where your ruby is located. [Capistrano RVM Docs](https://github.com/capistrano/rvm#configuration)

Answer (score 21):

It's an issue related to ruby upgrade but bundle package path was old. To resolve it you should reinstall the `bundler` package again using `gem`.

Uninstall from system

```
sudo gem uninstall bundler
```

Install again

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.10, trying to uninstall gives `Gem bundler-2.3.7 cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`. However, it is enough to just run `sudo gem install bundler` by itself to upgrade the `bundler` gem. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

After MacOSX High Sierra update got this issue. High Sierra updates ruby gem to version 2.3 but `xcpreety` command of Xcode 9 still using Ruby 2.0 which is unable to find now & gives bad interpreter.
Just go to Terminal & run

```
sudo gem install xcpretty
```

insert your password it will update your xcpretty to ruby v2.3 & that will resolve the issue.
Restart Xcode & do fresh clean build it works for me.
Hope it helps!!!